# not able to create table using Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Table

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I am new to php, Silex and I am developing a small app using these technologies on the top of a code base.

from the code base I am getting a database object - $app['db'] - ( something like connection object) like this -

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
    'db.options' => array(
        'driver'   => 'pdo_sqlite',
        'path'     => __DIR__.'/app.db',
    ),
));
```

$app['db'] can be used for fetching data from the existing database and is working properly.

But when I try to add a table to the existing db using following code -

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Table;
$schema = $app['db']->getSchemaManager();
if (!$schema->tablesExist('users'))
{
    $users = new Table('users');
    $users->addColumn('id', 'integer', array('unsigned' => true, 'autoincrement' => true));
    $users->setPrimaryKey(array('id'));
    $users->addColumn('username', 'string', array('length' => 32));
    $users->addUniqueIndex(array('username'));
    $users->addColumn('password', 'string', array('length' => 255));
}
```

and later on try to insert record in the user table I get following exception -

3/3 TableNotFoundException in AbstractSQLiteDriver.php line 58: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?' with params [0]:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: users

2/3 PDOException in PDOConnection.php line 79: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: users

1/3 PDOException in PDOConnection.php line 77: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: users

I verified that the above piece of code is being executed. please tell me a way to create a new table in the database when I don't know the credentials.

I suspect that I might not be having write access to the database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have created new table definition, but didn't save it to DB.

```
if (!$schema->tablesExist('users'))
{
    $users = new Table('users');
    ...
    $schema->createTable($users); // save to DB
}
```